# Tomcat 7 MBean -- Connection Pool details

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, tomcat7, jmx

I have a Tomcat 7 server instance with a connection pool defined via the

```
<Resource type="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl"
 ...
 ...
>
```

The connection itself functions fine. But when I connect via VisualVM/JConsole and browse the MBeans to the defined Resource, I only see 5 attributes -- "auth", "description", "modelerType", "name", "scope" and "type".

I thought there was a way to look at number of connections used, number of idle connections and other pool statistics, but haven't found anything.

I've also tried other types of connections -- namely, `"oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"` and even the plain `"javax.sql.DataSource"` for type with the driver as "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver".

Any pointers would be appreciated.